# Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at cursor.pl line 5

Tags: oracle, perl

I have this script in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
while () {
  if (/^PARSING IN CURSOR/../END OF STMT/) {
    if (/^PARSING IN CURSOR/) {
      s/^PARSING IN CURSOR \#//;
      s/ [a-z]+=/!/g;
      s/\n$/!/;
      $_="$.!$_";
    }
    unless (/^END OF STMT/) {
      print;
    }
  }
}
```

when executing in llinux perl cursor.pl shows the message: **Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at cursor.pl line 5.**
what the file does is load an external table in oracle a trace file and when I select the table it does not return anything and it remains running.

Comment: Did you really mean `while ()`? Or should that be `while (<>)`?

Answer (score 4):

```
while () { ... }
```

describes an infinite loop (it is treated as `while (1) { ... }`) and it is why your program remains running. Based on the rest of your script, I will guess that what you meant to say was

```
while (<>) { ... }
```

which is equivalent to

```
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) { ... }
```

In this construction, Perl reads a line from the default file descriptor and assigns it to the variable `$_`. When the file handle is exhausted and there is no more input to read, Perl sets `$_` to the undefined value, and the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

> what the file does is load an external table in oracle a trace file

No, it doesn't. There is no file IO happening in your code

There is nothing in your code to set `$_` to a defined value, so the regex pattern matches will generate this warning

`while () { ... }` is just an indefinite loop, and most likely your intention was to read from a file specified on the command line. It should instead be

```
while ( <> ) {
    ...
}
```